# Calculating inductance using PEEC Model

Tags: inductance, mutual-inductance

I'm learning of how inductance is modeled in wires by breaking them down into smaller filaments. I don't understand how the different inductances add up. Say we want to calculate the total inductance in these wires:
[image]

The way I understand it is done is that we break each wire into filaments and then go through these steps:

1. for each filament, calculate its self inductance using the self inductance equation
2. for each pair of filaments inside the wire we calculate their mutual inductance (do we do this? I'm not sure)
3. We sum the inductances of step 1 and 2 as if they are parallel inductances (again not sure)

For a PEEC model how can the mutual inductances be calculated between the wires we perform the mutual inductance calculation of the wire's filaments to each other and add them in series as well, or we add them in parallel?

Thank you

Comment: Inductance is meaningless without a driving circuit and a load.

Comment: @Andyaka Then how does one build a 100uH inductor?

Comment: http://staff.www.ltu.se/~jekman/PEEC/Program/MultiPEEC_UG.pdf

Comment: Please don’t try and be clever. You have not indicated where the inductance is measured and, you have shown three metal conductors so, get your question straight and unambiguous first.

Comment: When I instantiate real inductors in my Cadence schematics from a foundry PDK, the PDK doesn't ask me what the driver or load is. It gives me an inductor. NOW, if you want to know what the inductance is over freq then I agree with you, I'm not interested in skin effect or Q, just how PEEC works.

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on the current through the wire. So one would need to pick a direction (red) and it's apparent magnetic field direction (blue). You then pull out your electromagnetics book and look up the coupling equations between the conductor shape you have.

[image]

But the coupling (shown lower right) only really makes sense if you have a source and a load with an AC current. You can then take a circuit diagram of all three conductors which ends up being two transformers in a row.

The circuit also has capacitance so that needs to be accounted for if one is designing antennas or HF circuits.

[image]

Comment: thanks, I'm asking specifically how a PEEC model does it, do the filaments add in serries or parallel, and do you count mutual inductance within a wire's filaments to itself as self inductance.

Comment: That shows the capacitance and inductance for each node, there really isn't any series resistance because Air and PCB  are high resistance. There is series resistance between each conductor and ground through the PCB. Once you have capacitance and inductance, you could transform it to PEEC

Comment: That's a great picture thank you.